# Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use a simple case statement to check the value of `$item`, which is returned as an array. The code returns the default case statement even though the array is equal to `"iphones"`. Is there a simple way that I can get the value as a string?

This is the value of the array

```
object(stdClass)#209 (1) {
  ["item"]=>
  string(7) "iphones"
}
```

and this is my code

```
class ItemController extends BaseController {

        public function item ($item) {

        $item = DB::table('Catagories')->where('item', $item)->first();

        if (isset($item)) {

        switch ($item) {
              case "iphones":
                echo "iphone!";
                break;
              case "phones":
                echo "phones!";
                break;
              case "tablets":
                echo "tablets!";
                break;
              default:
              echo "string";
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please post '$item' array format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an array; it's an object. You can just access it like this:

```
$item->item
```

`$item` is an object with a property named `item`, so you use the syntax above.

Comment: Thank you so much! And I have another question. If I'm passing a view with an object attached, like so... 'return View::make('general.buy')
         ->with('item', $item);' , what is the first parameter of the with() method?

Comment: I'm not sure what your other question is, but you should ask it as a new question, using the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

Array elements can be converted to a string like such:

```
<?php
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
echo implode(" ",$arr);
?>
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)